# Copy Matlab figure to Power Point with exact same axis and font size

Tags: matlab, powerpoint, matlab-figure

I am trying to copy a Matlab (2013b) figure to Power Point (2013) with the axis and font size I have specified in Matlab.

Here is what I have tried:

```
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual'); 
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters'); 
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 18 14]);
set(gcf,'Units','centimeters','position',[x0,y0,18,14])

set(gca,'Units','centimeters','position', [x0,y0,width,height],'ActivePositionProperty','outerposition')
```

The Matlab figure itself looks fine but when I click Edit --> Copy figure and then paste in Power Point, the figure and font sizes change.

I have also tried changing the figure preferences and export options in Matlab but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: In the figure, go to Edit > Copy options... > ensure "Match figure screen size" is checked, you also might want to change the copy format to "bitmap" in that window